# Fetch variable sized arrays type Array<T> from Observable<T>

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm working with an observable that receives a stream of bytes, one by one, that can be put together to represent serialized data. I wan't to transform this stream into a stream of serialized data `Array<Byte>`. The data are MQTT packets.

The size of each array is variable, depending on the value indicated on positions `1..m`. The longer the array, the more bytes needed to indicate the size. The highest value bit indicates that a byte is the last byte used to calculate the remaining size. After calculating the remaining size `n` through the given bytes, I only need to await the following `n` bytes and then put them together on an `Array<Byte>` and restart the process.

Is there any operator I can use to handle this situation?

**EDIT 1**

This code seems to be doing the trick without any operators, but it doesn't look to be the rx way to do it:

```
ArrayList<Byte> buffer = new ArrayList();
int n = 0;
boolean fetchSize = false;
byteStream.subscribe (b -> {
    buffer.add(b)
    if (n == 0) {
        n = 1;
        fetchSize = true;
    }
    else if (fetchSize) {
        n *= b % 0x80;
        if ((b & 0x80) == 0) fetchSize = false;
    }
    else if (n > 1) n--;
    else {
        n = 0;
        dataObservable.onNext(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: My first bet was serial `take` operations, but that would not work. I thought about using `map`, managing states with outside variables, but that doesn't sound "reactive".

Comment: Not everything needs to be Rx. It's possible to use the `buffer()` operator with a secondary observable that does the collection of bytes, but it isn't pretty and won't be anywhere near as efficient as your code. You might consider wrapping the accumulator into a class to reduce the global variables.